# Div with style display:table has wrong height

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have a div that wraps a table with style display: table. Table contains div with height:500px http://jsfiddle.net/9ucm7z9h/:

```html
<div style="width: 400px; display: table; background-color: blue;">
    <div style="height: 100px; background-color: green; overflow: scroll">
        <table style="width: 100%;">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div id="test" style="height: 500px; background-color: yellow;">&nbsp;</div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

This code rendered differently in IE and Chrome/Firefox. It is a Chrome/Firefox bug? What can I do to force it rendered as in IE?

Comment: What are you trying to do? I'm sure there are easier ways to get there than your current markup.

Comment: Do you want the yellow div's overflow to be visible rather than scrolled? Or do you want the blue div to be 100px tall?

Comment: @TylerH I want the blue div to be 100px tall as in this example: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/9ucm7z9h/1/) but I can change only style of div with overflow:scroll, or add some wrapper div. I can't change root div and table in my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug which can be eradicated by triggering the layout somehow.

**First of all**, the child element of one ruled as `display:table` might turn into `display:table-row` or `display:table-cell` by default, even if not written via the CSS rules. Browsers always try to correct or fix things which obviously here do not work out properly.

Trying to trigger layout using `float` or `display:inline-block` here looks like it fixes the misbehavior of the parent displayed as `table`, at least in Firefox.

http://jsfiddle.net/9ucm7z9h/3/

You can find a bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=250770&q=display%20table%20height&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).

Comment: What do you mean by "triggering layout" in this case? I have always thought of it as an IE-specific term referring to `hasLayout`, and not relevant to any other browsers.

Comment: well  old IEs had that "haslayout" thing and the quirk or not mode,  but i do not talk about this IE typical thing, just about layout (shared by most of all browser, IE7 included). For instance basicly using overflow:hidden, or display:table/inline-block or even float/position:absolute when you deal with floatting elements. My english is not good enough to explain technicly or clearly enough but the hint: "how to deal with floats" should be good enough to understand what "layout behavior" i talk about and be a start to do some search :) if you are not familiar with this.

Comment: @BoltClock do you have any feed back about the fiddle linked ?

Comment: In that case I think what you mean by "layout" are block formatting contexts.

Comment: @GCyrillus Thank you, it works. I found bug report for this issue: [250770](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=250770&q=display%20table%20height&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Week%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified). They wrap div(overflow:scroll) with table as workaround.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks for correcting me, i shall remember the proper words to use ;)

Comment: @PaulG thanks for your feed back, i'll add this issue link to the answer.